# Android: Fragment : View not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-canvas

I am new to android development. I have create a view that I want to display in a fragment within an activity.

Here is an excerpt of my view:

```
public class CalendarView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            displayTitleDate(canvas);
            displayNavigation(canvas);
            displayDays(canvas);
            displayNumbers(canvas);
            highlightRect(canvas);
            invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Here is an excerpt of the fragment:

```
public class MyCalendarFragment extends Fragment {

    private CalendarView calendarView;

    public static MyCalendarFragment newInstance()
    {
        return new MyCalendarFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        calendarView = new CalendarView(getActivity());
        return calendarView;
    }

}
```

And finally the excerpt of my activity code:

```
public class EditPersonActivity extends Activity {

    private Fragment calendarFrag;
    private Fragment currentFrag;
    private FragmentTransaction fragTrans;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_person);
        calendarFrag = MyCalendarFragment.newInstance();
        fragTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragTrans.add(R.id.edit_layout, calendarFrag);
        fragTrans.commit();
    }
}
```

My view does not show up at all. I guess this is a lifecycle issue. I have also tried to override the onMeasure method in the view but this does not change anything. Besides, it works when the view is embedded in an activity instead of a fragment. Any help is very welcome. Thx in advance.

Comment: Does it work when you inflate a layout for your fragment ?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to inflate a linear layout for my fragment and this dit not work neither. When I get a reference to the layout defined in the xml file, I try to add programmatically my view to it, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have solved my issue by using a Custom View directly into the xml file describing the fragment.

```
<com.mycompany.view.CalendarView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In the java code implementing the view, I had to override one of the constructor this way:

```
public CalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        //Other code here
}
```

And finally, I had to override the onMeasure(...) method:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width, height;
    Point size = new Point();
    WindowManager w = ((Activity)getContext()).getWindowManager();
    w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
    height = (int) (size.x * 1.5);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

Et voila, it works. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can replace `doOnPreDraw` -> (on) -> `doOnLayout`.